# wit.ai quantity not working

Tags: nlp, wit.ai

I am unable to setup the wit/quantity entity. There is no documentation regarding this except for the tooltip.

for example:

1. I need to say, order two fries.
2. Order a lamb burger

Entities:

- products [keyword]
- with all the products (ex: fries, lamb burger,
  etc.) units [keyword]
- empty wit/quantity.

I tried to train the model. It was only able to recognize product. It does not learn when I teach it to recognize the quantity.

Any help is appreciated.